# Frame refresh conflicting timeout and requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I use this on a lower canvas:

```
var requestAnimFrame =  window.requestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
                        window.msRequestAnimationFrame  ||  
                        window.oRequestAnimationFrame   || 
                        function(callback) {
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
                        };
```

I am using this for a canvas layer that is above the lower one:

```
function DrawSpawnAnimation() {


    anim();
}

 function anim() {

        ctxAnimation.drawImage(spriteSheet, ExplodeFrame * 100, 2740,100,100,explodeX,explodeY,100,100);

        if (ExplodeFrame < 5) {
            ExplodeFrame++;
            setTimeout(anim, 500);

        } 

      //alert("Show current frame of animation"); - this shows the animation works, it just does 
      // not show it one frame per half second.
    }
```

My problem is the animation just flickers in a millisecond on screen. Is the lower canvas refresh messing it up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here's how to use 1 RAF ticker to animate 2 canvases.**

The RAF ticker will fire 60 times per second.

The top canvas will animate 30x per second (Every 2nd frame when TopFrameCount drops to 0).

The bottom canvas will animate 2x per second (Every 30th frame when BottomFrameCount drops to 0)

```
var RAFfps = 60;

var TopFPS=30;
var BottomFPS=2;

var TopFrameCount=(RAFfps/TopFPS)-1;
var BottomFrameCount=(RAFfps/BottomFPS)-1;


var counter2fps=0;

function draw() {
    setTimeout(function() {

        requestAnimFrame(draw);

        // if the top canvas counter has expired, 
        // animate the top canvas
        if(--TopFrameCount<=0){

            // put top canvas drawing stuff here

            // reset the top counter
            TopFrameCount==(RAFfps/TopFPS)-1;
        }

        // if the bottom canvas counter has expired, 
        // animate the bottom canvas
        if(--BottomFrameCount<=0){

            // put bottom canvas drawing stuff here

            // reset the top counter
            BottomFrameCount=(RAFfps/BottomFPS)-1;
        }

    }, 1000 / fps);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without going near the lower canvas, just having it run on the upper canvas and letting the lower canvas continue on as if nothing is happening?

Comment: Do both canvases need animation?  If so, then no -- there is just 1 RAF ticker.  You can have multiple setTimeouts, but that would be taking a step backward in performance.  You really can handle multiple canvas animations with RAF + counters.

Comment: Because I have requestAnimFrame(Loop);  for my lower canvas, Its just getting the top layer that needs a longer wait is confusing me. The top layer is an explosion animation, the bottom layer is just the fps for player movement.

Comment: Edited my answer with different explanation.  Does this explanation help?